# how do I set X-Frame-Options response header to allow-from value(s) using spring java config?

Tags: spring-security, http-headers, spring-java-config, x-frame-options

How do I set X-Frame-Options response header with a value of allow-from using spring java config?

```java
http.headers().disable()
    .addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(
      new WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy(
        Arrays.asList("https://example1.com", "https://example2.com"))));
```

In Http Response headers I get:

> X-Frame-Options:"ALLOW-FROM DENY".

Why aren't my origins listed in the header value?

Answer (score 7):

I ended up adding my headers statically like below:

```java
http
    .headers().frameOptions().disable()
    .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "ALLOW-FROM example1.com"));
```

Comment: With Spring security 4.1 we can do like so,                                 http.headers().frameOptions().disable()
    .addHeaderWriter(
      new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(new StaticAllowFromStrategy(URI.create("https://www.example.com"))));

Comment: This is not working for me with multiple domains, headers()
            .addHeaderWriter(
                new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(
                    new WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy(
                        Arrays.asList("https://www.test2.com","https://www.test2.com")
                    )
                )
            )

Comment: This doen't restrict from the other websites. we can create the XFrame for our website even after adding the addHeaderWriter with frameOptions disabled. DOESN't WORK

Answer (score 2):

```
//disable 默认策略。 这一句不能省。 
http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
//新增新的策略。 
http.headers().addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(
            new WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy(
                    Arrays.asList("http://itaobops.aliexpress.com", 
"https://cpp.alibaba-inc.com",
                            "https://pre-cpp.alibaba-inc.com"))));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use X-Content-Security-Policy and Content-Security-Policy instead of X-Frame-Options which give much more flexibility to allow iframe access to multiple domains with wildcard.

Here is an example -

```
http.csrf().disable()
.headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter(
        "X-Content-Security-Policy",
        "frame-ancestors self *.domain1.com *.domain2.com"))
.and()
.headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter(
        "Content-Security-Policy",
        "frame-ancestors self *.domain1.com *.domain2.com"))
```

X-Frame-Options value will be discarded.

Comment: http.headers().contentSecurityPolicy("frame-ancestors self *.domain1.com *.domain2.com") would be even more better.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and didn't find an answer. Doesn't matter how I tried to configure it, header was always incorrect.

My workaround for that it to use delegating header writer from the Spring framework [doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/reference/html/headers.html#headers-delegatingrequestmatcherheaderwriter)

Thanks to that I built a logic to always set SAMEORIGIN excluding some whitelist:

```
new DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter(
            new NegatedRequestMatcher(
                    new OrRequestMatcher(
                            whiteLists
                    )
            ),
            new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN);
```

Logic behind that: if any from white list matches then don't add header, otherwise add header with SAMEORIGIN value.

I think it's worth to consider because AFAIK not all browsers support ALLOW-FROM.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet for security config that worked for me in Spring Boot 2.3:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
            .addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(new StaticAllowFromStrategy(URI.create("example.com"))))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allow multiple URLs as follows, but I don't know whether this is the proper way or not, still, it works properly.

```java
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .headers().defaultsDisabled()
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .headers()
                .cacheControl()
                .and()
                .contentTypeOptions()
                .and()
                .httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable()
                .and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-FRAME-OPTIONS",
                    "ALLOW-FROM example1.com",
                    "ALLOW-FROM example2.com",
                    "ALLOW-FROM example3.com",
                    "ALLOW-FROM example4.com",
                    "ALLOW-FROM example5.com"));
}
```